# «Да, я не люблю пролетариаТА». Почему?

Tags: грамматика, падежи, управление, родительный-или-винительный

[М. Булгаков. Собачье сердце](http://books.rusf.ru/unzip/xussr_av/bulgam21.htm?3/13):

> — Вы ненавистник пролетариата! — гордо сказала женщина.
>    — Да, я не люблю пролетариа**та**, — печально согласился Филипп Филиппович и нажал кнопку.

Почему *пролетариа**та***, а не *пролетариа**т***?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По поводу исходной версии вопроса, который затем почему-то сократили. Да, редакций много, все разные, но везде именно *пролетариата*. На мой взгляд, тут эта форма вполне правильная, даже единственно правильная стилистически.

Почему я так категоричен? Дело на мой взгляд, не столько в Филиппе Филипповиче и уж совсем не в разнице разговорной и книжной речи. Профессор вполне владеет разговорной речью:

> В пять часов дня событие: впервые слова, произнесенные существом, не
>   были оторваны от окружающих явлений, а явились реакцией на них.
>   Именно, когда профессор приказал ему:
>   - *Не бросай объедки* на пол...

Цитирую по http://www.vehi.net/mbulgakov/sobach.html

Здесь, правда, другой глагол, не чувственный, но ведь и он исторически требовал родительного.

> Давай всякому то, в чем он на сей раз имеет нужду; *не читай
>   нравоучений* тому человеку, который умирает с голоду, а дай ему кусок
>   хлеба; *не бросай рубля* тому, кто утопает, а вытащи его из воды. [Н. М.
>   Карамзин. Письма русского путешественника (1793)]

(Из нацкорпуса, курсив мой.)

К тому же почти век назад стилистика была, судя по всему, иной.

> При переходных глаголах с отрицанием сильноуправляемое имя со
>   знач. объекта может иметь форму род. или вин. п. *Единая старая норма
>   обязательного род. п. при глаголах с отрицанием* в современном языке
>   под влиянием разговорной речи не выдерживается: во многих случаях
>   употребление вин. п. не только предпочитается, но и является
>   единственно правильным.

АГ-80,  § 2667 и последующие, курсив мой.
http://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik/roditelnyiy-vinitelnyiy-padeji-znacheniem-96659.html

Можно с большой долей уверенности сказать, что в двадцатых годах прошлого века эта норма еще не была потревожена современными разговорными тенденциями.

Кстати. Вот уж кого трудно заподозрить в использовании книжной речи, так это Шарикова. Однако же и он использует форму родительного падежа в аналогичной конструкции.

> "Не люблю кутерьмы в квартире", - раздумывал он...

Цитирую по http://www.vehi.net/mbulgakov/sobach.html

Этот факт заставляет сильно сомневаться в том, что Булгаков что-то там специально подчеркивает применительно конкретно к Преображенскому.
Скорее всего, тогдашние нормы просто еще не подверглись влиянию современного разговорного стиля, допускающего винительный падеж при отрицании.

Это самое простое объяснение. *И по принципу бритвы Оккама - самое правильное*.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54054/discussion-on-answer-by-morkovkin-------).

Comment: "И по принципу бритвы Оккама - самое правильное".  Никогда не поздно узнавать новое (я о себе).  Вам - спасибо!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да не за что. "Бритва Оккама", если совсем по-простому, то это  некое правило здравого смысла ("принцип экономии"), недоказуемое в рамках строгой постулативной философии, которое означает ***"Не надо искать сложностей там, где все можно объяснить просто"***. В более продвинутой версии - ***"не надо плодить сущностей"***. А научно (почти) - тут. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%9E%D0%BA%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: К великому сожалению, СТОЛЬКО мозгов, чтобы пообщаться с Вами на РАВНЫХ поводу строгой постулативной философии и прочих сложностей и сущностей, у меня нет.  Могу только цитировать Старджона: "Ничто и никогда не является абсолютно верным".

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова от незаслуженных похвал я чувствую себя неловко. Если бы философия была профильным предметом на ресурсе, я бы еще понял. А тут, право слово, не стоит подобных комплиментов. Не стоит оно того. Я просто дал информацию о предмете Вас заинтересовавшим. Но это в любом случае оффтоп.

Answer (score 5):

По-моему, Булгаков подчеркнул, что факультативное употребление родительного и винительного падежей при переходном глаголе с отрицанием связано со **стилистическим** различием: *конструкции с родительным падежом характерны для книжной речи, с винительным — для разговорной*.

Профессор принципиально говорил на правильном литературном, т. е. книжном языке, тем более с малокультурными домкомовцами, которых он презирал.

```
     — Да, я не люблю пролетариата, — печально согласился Филипп Филиппович...
```

Печально, потому что родину, страну он любил, но не тех, кто пришёл к власти. Для него пролетариат не рабочие люди, а средоточие бескультурья, грязи, подлости, поэтому фраза звучала так же, как бы звучало "не люблю грязи, хамства, подлости". Это целое явление, понятие отвлечённое (а отвлечённое понятие употребляется с родительным падежом).

Так что родительный падеж здесь - осознанный выбор, винительный упрощает понимание авторской позиции, убирает психологизм сцены.

Answer (score 2):

Пролетарий ― одушевленное существительное, поэтому можно  сказать: **я не люблю пролетариев.** Пролетариат ― собирательное существительное (по Энгельсу, это   общественный класс), поэтому следует сказать: **я не люблю пролетариат.** Кстати, в фильме "Собачье сердце" эта фраза исправлена: [Да, я не люблю пролетариат | citatyizfilmov.ru](http://citatyizfilmov.ru/video/2763)

**Примеры из современных текстов:** Теперь настоящих **пролетариев** можно найти только где-нибудь в Китае или Индии. Так и говорили: право ― это одна из цепей, которой буржуазия оковала **пролетариат**!

Поэтому остается предполагать, почему в авторском варианте использована неправильная грамматическая форма, причем произнесенная образованным профессором. **Возможно, он не считал пролетариат классом и был об этих людях другого мнения** (то есть в самой форме есть скрытый подтекст).

**А как же отрицание?** Известно, что Р.п. вместо В.п. при наличии отрицания используется не всегда, на эту тему Розенталь дает длинный перечень частных факторов, которые могут повлиять на выбор падежа. Собирательные существительные он не рассматривает, но ведь мы не говорим: **не люблю студенчества, человечества, молодежи и электората.** Скорее всего, в речи должна быть обозначена одушевленность единичных предметов и неодушевленность их собирательного единства. Возможно, таким образом удобно дополнительно **обозначить собирательное значение** этих существительных.

**Примечание**

Надо сказать, что термины "пролетарий, пролетариат" не так просты для понимания, их этимология и значение толкуется по-разному.

Слово «пролетарий» proletarius ― «производящий потомство» (от лат. proles).  При проведении переписи населения те люди, у которых не было собственности, в графе об имуществе писали – «дети» (пролес). Патриции  презирали этих граждан, но не могли не признать, что они приносили большую пользу, производя на свет многочисленное потомство.  Но не все согласны с таким толкованием и считают, что значение слова изменилось и  уже в Древнем Риме речь шла не о "производителях детей", а об неимущем и неподатном сословии.

Другая проблема  **юридического характера**. Пролетарии были неимущими, но свободными людьми, в то время как марксисты говорят о наемном **рабстве,** сравнивая современный пролетариат не с римским плебсом, а с римскими рабами.

Comment: Я не люблю весны, сказал Пушкин. Весна – одушевлённое?

Comment: Пушкин писал: "Уж я ли не любил моей Дуни", но теперь такая форма считается устаревшей. Для одушевленных существительных, в частности имен, при отрицании не делается замена падежей: люблю Дуню (В.п.) - не люблю Дуню (В.п.), в противном случае возникнут проблемы с выражением одушевленности. §201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm

Comment: И при чем тут Дуня и вообще одушевленность?

Comment: @Sibylla, извините. Поправьте, пожалуйста, в Вашем ответе: пролетарий -пролетария. С уважением

Comment: Извините, что не сразу отвечаю, но я не могу понять, что нужно исправить. Пролетарий - пролетария, пролетариев, все эти формы возможны. Пролетарии - рабочие, пролетариат - класс рабочих, поэтому я  беру для сравнения форму мн. числа (пролетариев).

Answer (score 1):

Обсуждение темы выбора Р.п. или В. п. при наличии  отрицания для меня лично никак не решило проблемы и оставило чувство глубоко неудовлетворения, но в то же время позволило более ясно **представить эту проблему в целом.**

Участники  конференции выбрали **самое простое решение**, взяв за основу  разговорный стиль В.п. и книжный стиль Р.п., и это довольно странно:  между этими падежами  существуют намного **более  сложные отношения.** (С другой стороны,  простые решения нам всегда нравятся, так как не требуют больших усилий для понимания).

Основным значением падежа, из которого следуют все частные значения,  является его **направленность**. В.п. обозначает прямую направленность действия на предмет, а для Р.п.  основным значением  является отложительно-достигательное  направление действия  относительно границ предмета (предлоги ДО, ОТ, ИЗ, ОКОЛО). В этом случае  **значения этих  падежей не пересекаются.**

Но существуют  **три  темы**,  в которых приходится делать выбор между Р.п.  и В.п.  **Первая тема** связана со значением **партитивности** (обозначением части предмета) у Р.п.: выпил воду  (В.п.) – выпил воды (Р.п.). **Вторая тема** – это обозначение **одушевленности предмета**, а **третья** – употребление Р.п. вместо В.п. **при отрицании.** Каждая тема  имеет свои **особенности:** так, партитивность важна для  вещественных и собирательных существительных. **Тема одушевленности**  интересна тем, что одушевленность можно выразить только  для сущ.  м.р. ед.ч. и всех сущ. мн. числа.:  вижу мальчика, мальчиков и девочек  (форма Р.п. для В.п.) и вижу стол (форма И.п. для В.п.).

**Тема отрицания**  связана с выбором Р.п. при отсутствии предмета (тогда нет прямого перехода действия на предмет), **но выбор Р.п. ясен в самых простых вариантах вида  «есть дом/нет дома»,** в других же случаях необходимость в Р.п.  может затушёвываться, не казаться обязательной, и тогда используется В.п.  Поэтому грамматическая точность требует Р.п. (значение книжности и усиленного отрицания),  а выбор В.п. объявляется ослабленным отрицанием и разговорностью стиля.

А теперь вспомним **про первые две темы** (партитивность и одушевленность), которые тоже влияют на выбор падежа и вполне  **могут потеснить  обозначение отрицания,** и тогда мы начинаем говорить о разговорном стиле, об ослабленном отрицании, о грамотности пользователей, в то время как **семантический критерий является основным.**

Это становится ясным, если  обратиться к **правилу Розенталя**, где влияние частных факторов обозначено по пунктам: Р.п – 8 пунктов, В.п. – 13 пунктов,  и только **факультативное решение связывается  со стилем речи.** Кроме того, не стоит быть уверенным, что все факторы здесь учтены и обозначены. **И вот вопрос: что же о них никто и ничего не сказал в нашей дискуссии?**

И наконец обратимся  к нашему **герою-пролетариату** и посмотрим, какие темы  могут повлиять на выбор падежа.  Пролетарий (рабочий)  ―  одуш. сущ. м.р., две формы числа, одушевленность  может быть выражена. Пролетариат (класс) ―  собирательное сущ. м.р.,  только ед.число, неодушевленное.   **Но одушевленность может быть ошибочно понята, если заменить  винительный падеж  родительным.**

Если посмотреть в Нацкорпусе фразу «**я не люблю**», то  Р.п.  при отрицании там  отнюдь  не в лидерах,  и совсем не разговорность влияет на выбор В.п. **Вот и в нашем случае лучше не обозначать отрицание, чтобы  пролетариат не казался нам одушевленным.** Поэтому давайте остановимся на фразе «Я не люблю пролетариат».

Comment: *Участники конференции* - это какой конференции, простите? **O_o** Если вы о том, что что тут обсуждалось, так я видел ваши разборки с Niemand'ом, на конференцию это мало походило. А если предметно, то это Людмила задала такую градацию разговорный стиль против книжного, что, конечно же, очень узко вообще, но в рамках того тезиса, который Людмила отстаивает (о книжности речи ФФП),  вполне достаточно. Другое дело, что я сам этот тезис не разделяю. И уж совсем "третье дело", это ваш ответ в нынешнем виде, который далеко выходит за рамки конкретного вопроса о выборе падежа у Булгакова.

Comment: "Пролетариат" ни с каких позиций грамматически не одушевлен. Как не одушевлена толпа, народ и многие другие подобные слова, несущие собирательное значение. Понимаете, способ проверки одушевленности через глагол с отрицанием - это нечто. Наоборот, если существительное одушевлено, то можно как-то рассматривать его падеж при отрицании в плане некоторой корреляции выбора падежа с одушевленностью объекста. Но ни в каких более случаях "пролетариат" не проявляет ни малейшей склонности быть одушевленным. Так что ваше объяснение через одушевленность представляется совершенно ошибочным.

Comment: Мой второй ответ выходит за рамки Булгакова,  но он посвящен теме выбора Р.п. или В.п. в общем плане, а не в рамках тезиса о книжности/разговорности, который у Розенталя явно не на первом месте. Это всего лишь призыв к вам, уважаемые  коллеги,  посмотреть на проблему сверху, а не делать поспешные  выводы, призыв обратиться к реальным текстам, просмотреть их и понять, как вопрос решается на практике.

Comment: Что касается "конференции", то форум единогласно высказался за "разговорный стиль", который сам по себе далеко не ясный предмет. И я не большой любитель разборок, но мне не хочется, чтобы сайт превращали в пересылочный пункт  для поиска нужного правила. Конечно, пролетариат - существительное неодушевленное, но Р.п. провоцирует  такое понимание, почему - я подробно объяснила, нечего добавить.

Comment: *форум единогласно высказался* - Что вы имеете в виду? И простите, вопрос был всего лишь о том, что вы назвали "конференцией". Впрочем, с утверждением, что "форум единогласно высказался" я тем более не согласен. Я лично ни за кокой "разговорный стиль" не высказывался, я высказался совсем за другое объяснение

Comment: А  мне показалось, что вы постоянно говорите о стилевых различиях и слово "разговорный" употребляете неоднократно.  Думаю, что участники форума  это тоже для себя отметили, голосуя за ваш ответ. Конференция, обсуждение, дискуссия - какая разница? Я не услышала иного мнения,  кроме рассуждений о стиле. Разговорный стиль сам по себе, как мне кажется, плохо изучен,  я сомневаюсь, что существуют в этой теме четкие определения и понимание причин  этого явления.