# Которые / которых

Tags: грамотная-речь, склонение, падежи

Никак не найдем консенсус с женой. Я сказал: "Где мои джинсы, которых не жалко?"
Она на меня посмотрела, как на дурака, и сказала: "Которые!!!"
А как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Ваша жена права (но не в плане взгляда :)).

Если речь идёт о неодушевлённом предмете, то у слова «[который](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9)» в винительном падеже окончание будет совпадать с именительным.
Если об одушевлённом – с родительным.

**Примеры:**

*Обе они смогут дружить на расстоянии и выносить мозг другим **людям**, неродным и котор**ых** не жалко* (А. Р. Мурадова, Земноводное в кармане).

*В тюрьмах сидело предостаточно **преступников**, котор**ых** не жалко пустить в расход* (Галина Герасимова, Механика невезения).

*Может быть, пока лучше предложить малышу старый **телефон**, **магнитофон**, **фотоаппарат** или **пульт**, котор**ые** не жалко «препарировать»* (Людмила Мардер, Портрет ребенка, живущего рядом со мной).

*А раз защититься от удара нельзя, значит, под него надо подставлять **корабли**, котор**ые** не жалко* (Макс Глебов, Оружие возмездия).

Подобный вопрос обсуждался здесь: [«Которые» или «которых»](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/470139/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147872/discussion-on-answer-by----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0):

Связано ли окончание с тем, одушевленный предмет или нет? не совсем, сокрее связано с тем, о чем идет речь, об объекте/понятии или о субъекте действия. И мне кажется тут не падежность, а другое.

> В комнате висели джинсы, которые не падали - ну уже криво, потому что:
> в комнате висели джинсы которым бельевая веревка не давала упасть.

Дело в том, что джинсы, не могут быть субъектом действия.

Давайте оживим джинсы:

> Джинсы, которые шагали сами - ну, вроде, можно.

Теперь люди:

> Люди, которые лежат в джинсах, в которых спят.
>
> 1)В комнате находилось много людей, которые туда были согнаны. /2) В комнате сидело и лежало много людей, которых туда согнали захватчики. /3) В комнате лежали и сидели люди, которых туда согнали как пленников.

Люди одушевленное? конечно, но "которых", потому что они в этой части предложения выступают в качестве объекта на который оказывается воздействие - люди подневольные, люди-пленники. Люди - это понятие, поэтому люди могут быть как субъектами, так и объектами.

Заметим, что:

Первое предложение не требует указание субъекта действия, достаточно страдательной формы согнаны.

Во втором предложении желательно указание субъекта "захватчики", если его не написать, придется выкручиваться и как-то это оправдывать. Много людей - с одной стороны одушевленное, однако, тут есть много - коллективное собирательное, люди становится неким "счетным словом", для объектов, пусть и живых. Счетные слова - это слова указывающие, что считаем, и люди тут ближе к числительному, чем к существительному - "много единиц людей". Я это только что придумал, возможно потому что в китайском языке, например, есть счетные слова, то есть там говорят не единиц, а особые слова, и, скажем, кур считают одним словом, а деревья другим, птиц - третьим, то есть это такие "местоимения-числительные", по которым понятно объекты какого класса имеются ввиду, и мне кажется здесь с люди происходит что-то подобное, это люди - но уже не совсем люди.

И третье предложение - "согнали (людей) как-пленников", были люди, стали люди-пленники. Переменной люди присвоили новый статус - пленники, когда согнали в комнату. Тут люди - это понятие, а не одушевленное/неодушевленное. Что такое люди? Это не люди - это пленники. Кто эти люди? Эти - пленники - необходима тире, потому что люди, это не существительное, это понятие.

Так что да, по простому можно опираться на одушевленность/неодушевленность, но не всегда. Но могут быть и сложные варианты:

> Ты не видел мои джинсы, в которых дыры?.. / Ты видел мои джинсы, которые в дырах? Ты видел не мои джинсы: мои в дырах/в моих дыры...(можно оба варианта)

> Где мои джинсы, в которых не жалко выйти в свет?/которые не жалко надеть для выхода в свет(а как тут?))))
>
> Я щеголяю в джинсах, в которых я хорошо выгляжу.

Хотя, может быть, тут не работает эта субъект-объектная модель, а просто выбор зависит от ***подчинения***.

Если джинсы на мне - то джинсы подчинены и "которые". А если я в джинсах - то я подчинен джинсам и "которых"/"в которых".

> Я люблю людей, которые лгут(мне).
>
> Я люблю людей, которых вижу.
>
> Я люблю людей, которые лгущие(мне).

Можно еще проверить сослагательным наклонением:

> Я люблю людей, которые могли бы лгать.
>
> Я люблю людей, которых мог бы видеть. (единственное число - которых)

И еще к вопросу одушевленности:

> Ты видел моих собак, которых не видно. - мои собаки, которых не вижу я.
>
> Ты видел моих собак, которые не видят. - мои собаки, которые не видят меня.

> Ты видел мои джинсы, которые не видно. - которые не видно мне.
>
> Ты не видел мои джинсы, которых не видно. - которых не вижу я.

И почему моих и мои? в чем разница в употреблении? Но:

> Ты не видел моих собак, которых не видно.
>
> Ты не видел моих джинсов, которых не видно. (хотя тут есть сомнение в корректности, может лучше : ты не видел мои джинсы, которые не видно? / ты не видал моих джинсов, которых не узнать - утверждение, а не вопрос) То есть тут вообще как-то сложно, но "которых", мне кажется можно употребить в ряде случаев.

Почему поменялось окончание у джинсы? А у собак не поменялось на собаков?

Хорошо, сделаем так:

> Ты видел моих псов, которых не видно? / ты не видел моих псов, которых не видно? / Ты видел мои псы, которые не видят, бегают. / Ты видел моих псов, которые не видят, но бегают.

То есть с псами все не так, как с собаками и не так, как с джинсами. Вопрос: пёс - это одушевленное? или пёс его знает?

Или вот еще можно так, если отойти от множественного:

> Продать раба, которого люблю.
>
> Продать ботинок, который люблю.
>
> Продать раба, который ленится. / Продать ботинок, который ленится
> одеться.
>
> Продать ботинок, который рвется. / Продать раба, который рвется
> работать.

То есть если попытаться поменять глаголы местами, то требуется уточнение инфинитива еще одним словом, тоже в инфинитиве.

Хотя:

> *Продать собаку, которая рвется - можно без уточнения, также как с ботинком.*

Или так:

Хочу отпустить раба/собаку. Раб/собака хочет в туалет.

> Я отпустил раба, котого хотел(отпустить). / Отпустил собаку, которая
> хотела(в туалет). / Отпустил раба, который хотел в туалет(требуется
> уточнение). / Отпустил собаку, которую хотел отпустить(опять требуется
> уточнения).

Почему? Они вроде одушевленные оба или нет? А вот пёс:

> Я отпустил пса, которого хотел отпустить. / Отпустил пса, который хотел в туалет. / Я выбросил ботинок, который хотел - только такая одна форма.

То есть пёс и раб - это слова одного класса? а собака и ботинок - это другой класс слов. Пёс и раб - это понятия. А собака и ботинок - это существительные. Либо нужна какая-то иная градация, чтобы обозначить все эти различия в необходимости уточнений при переходе?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147868/discussion-on-answer-by---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Sharon что значит "выражена одушевленность", почему то или иное является одушевленным или нет? Кстати,  вот еще пример: ты видел моих собак, которых не видно/ ты видел моих собак, которые не видят. Какие здесь падежи/одушевленность?

Comment: @Буратино
Обратите внимание на слово КОТОРЫЙ с двунаправленной связью. Оно согласуется в роде и числе с определяемым словом из главного предложения, но получает падеж в придаточном предложении, являясь подлежащим или дополнением. В заданном предложении это дополнение.

Comment: А "почему" одушевленность выражена через два  падежа,  я не знаю. Попробуйте решить эту задачу. Родительный падеж это вообще вещь в себе, он может выражать: (1) одушевленность;  (2) партитивность;  (3) отрицание. А почему так? Эти значения могут конкурировать между собой. Интересное обсуждение на эту тему. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430089/Да-я-не-люблю-пролетариаТА-Почему  Может, дадите ответ?) Любопытно было бы услышать...

Comment: @Sharon КОТОРЫЙ с двунаправленной связью, так то так, но не забывайте, что связь может иметь направление подчинения. То есть связь - это не тире, где равноправие, а связь - это направление откуда куда идти, понимать фразу. И я придумал еще несколько странных примеров. Которые идут в разрез с предположением о достаточной одушевленности.

Comment: Падежи предмета в главном и придаточном предложении независимы. Вы их, пожалуйста, не связывайте между собой. Вообще говоря, тему одушевленности неудобно изучать в СПП с союзным словом который.

Comment: @Sharon в каком-то примере или во всех?

Comment: Независимы во всех случаях, могут случайно совпадать.

Comment: Еще один важный момент: одушевленность могут выражать только сущ. м.р. 2 скл. и сущ. мн. числа

Comment: @Sharon можно подробнее? или примеры, что выражает одушевленность, а что нет? То есть юноша - это не неодушевленное/одушевленное?

Comment: @Sharon и что такое партитивность, какой-то латинский термин?

Comment: А вы его не узнаете? Часть  – part.  Предметное отношение целого и части. Выпить воду  – выпить воды. Юноша - 1 скл, не выражает одушевленность, в отличие от мальчика.

Comment: @Sharon хорошо, маличик - одушевленное, а мальчишка - не выражает одушевленность?) И слова женского рода тоже не будут выражать одушевленность? Это великолепно. А борщ - неодушевленное? Налить борщ, налить борща?

Comment: Я же сказала: одуш. только для сущ. м.р.2 скл и всех сущ. мн. числа. А почему – не знаю, это чистая грамматика, а не семантика. И вы смешиваете одушевленность и партитивность, а это разные свойства. Я вижу борщ, неод. Налейте борща – партитивность.

Comment: @Sharon  Про портативность я немного понял.  То есть одушевленность 1 и 3 склонение не выражает? Я тут не понимаю, откуда это. Вроде одушевленные - это отвечающие на вопрос кто, а неодушевленные на вопрос что.

Comment: В языке есть понятие грамматической категории: число, род, падеж, одушевленность. У них есть грамматическая функция (грамматическая связь слов) и семантическая. Но семантика выражена только частично (например, род неодуш. предметов смысла не имеет), насколько это позволяет форма (это сложилось исторически). Вот и одушевленность имеет ограниченные возможности для выражения. А вот почему именно такие - это надо обращаться к исторической грамматике, да и то не сразу догадаешься, где искать. Мне эта информация не попадалась.

Comment: @Sharon но в школе учат, что одушевленные это отвечающие на вопрос кто?, а неодушевленные на вопрос что? - или не так? а как вы говорите, только для 2 склонения? Но мальчишка - он же такой же одушевленный может быть, как и мальчик или нет? Или если кукла мальчик - она одушевленная или нет? не понятно это совершенно. Откуда такое?

Comment: Тогда так. Вам не нравится, что одушевленность сущ. 1 и 3 склонения ед. числа не выражена. Предложите, как это можно сделать. Для 2 скл. это сделано путем совпадения окончаний В.п. с И.п. или Р.п. Мальчишка - одушевл., но эта одушевленность не выражена грамматически в падежах ед. числа, Но во мн.числе она выражена для всех сущ. В И.п. мы говорим кто? мальчишка, мальчик, юноша, мой. Возможностей в языке вполне достаточно.

Comment: @Sharon Одушевленность вряд ли может быть выражена во множественном. То есть она может подразумеваться, исходя из единственного числа, но это тоже такое себе занятие. Я не очень понимаю, откуда вы это взяли про именно 2 склонение. Даже педивикий пишет:  "одушевленность...базирующийся на наивном знании о классификации существительных и местоимений по типу референта: от безусловно «живых» (человек, собака, комар) до полностью «неодушевлённых» (камень, стол, бесконечность)" Тут есть вопрос к одушевленности/неодушевленности бесконечности, но это другой момент.

Comment: @Sharon "Но во мн.числе она выражена для всех сущ. В И.п. мы говорим кто? мальчишка, мальчик, юноша, мой." Мой - не очень понял к чему. Кто мальчик, мальчишка, собака -  одушевленные? или нет? я не понял. Кукла-мальчик - одушевленное? В школе учили что если кто - то одушевленное, если что - то неодушевленное. Ну и тоже есть ряд вопросов, бесконечность - это одушевленное или нет, или это не совсем существительное, так как от бесконечное - наречие...

Comment: Да, это я уже ошибаюсь (спутанное сознание в вечернее время). Категорию неодуш. выражают сущ.м.р. 2 скл., а во мн. числе мы просто применяем это понятие. Я тут нашла популярную статью, вам она поможет разобраться в теме лучше, чем я.  https://rus.1sept.ru/article.php?ID=200204103

Comment: @Sharon я понял. То есть вы хотели сказать, что одушевленность/неодушевленность важна для определения окончаний при ряде согласований существительных(или то, что считается существительными) второго лица, а также всех слов множественного числа. Так как "нет стены и нет жены" - окончание одинаковое, то есть тут нас не волнует одушевленность/неодушевленность. Однако, вижу стены - неодушевленное, вижу жён(а не жены) - одушевленное. Во множественном числе уже важно принимать во внимание одушевленность. Так?

Comment: Какая-то подстава в ваших словах))  Учтите еще один момент. Нет жены, стены, мальчика, девочки, стен, жен, мальчиков, девочек. Но это просто Р. п., а категория одушевленности относится к В.п.  Именно В.п. имеет ФОРМУ И.п. для неодуш. сущ. и форму Р.п. для одуш. сущ. , причем определенного склонения и числа. Я вижу жену, стену (1 скл.), мальчика (2 скл),  девочку (1 скл.), стены (мн.ч.), жен (мн.ч.), мальчиков, девочек (мн.ч.). А теперь посмотрите на этот В.п. (я вижу) и определите одуш. и неодуш. существительные.

Comment: @Sharon то есть одушевленные имеют одинаковые окончания для родительного и винительного падежей, а неодушевленные меняют окончание в винительном падеже, на форму в именительном падеже? А кто сказал, что это именительный или винительный падеж, вопрос в винительном совпадает с вопросом в именительном - что, а что если у так называемых неодушевленных нет именительного падежа, есть только винительный, а у одушевленных есть только винительный падеж, а родительного нет?

Comment: @Sharon То есть: стоит дерево - именительный или винительный? Вопросы в винительном и именительном совпадают, окончания одинаковые, кроме того, если именительный вопрос кто? это про какое-то лицей лицо: кто - мальчик, мальчик рубит дерево. Что - дерево, дерево что делает, рубится мальчиком - творительный падеж, мальчик действует, рубит, творит. А вот берем предложение с деревом: Дерево падает на мальчика. Откуда предлог? совершенно другая конструкция, откуда равенство между падежностью одушевленных и нет? Есть ли вообще у дерева именительный падеж?

Comment: @Sharon Я вижу: дерево падает на мальчика. - именительный падеж - я, дерево - винительный падеж, мальчика - родительный. Я вижу: дерево падает на меня. Меня - родительный. Я вижу себя - себя, винительный. Я вижу меня не скажешь. Себя не имеет именительной формы и родительной: себе -дательный, себя - винительный/творительный, о себе - предложный. Себя - неодушевленное...

Comment: @Sharon А меня - одушевленное, но у него нет винительного падежа(и именительного). То есть падеж является результатом согласования, а не согласование является результатом падежа. Поэтому, нельзя сказать что-то о падеже, не зная как вообще оно согласовано, а если окончания одинаковые, то как определять падеж? То есть для начало, нужно понять что с чем в каком порядке связано, а потом уже говорить о падеже. Да, возможно одушевленность/неодушевленность и понимание об этом идет раньше согласованности, род слова идет раньше, но падеж не определяет согласование, падеж - это просто очевидное в конце.

Comment: @Sharon там творительный падеж надо убрать, творительный есть: собой, мной.

Comment: Ваша точка зрения очень нестандартная))  Я, вероятно, завтра отвечу на ваши комментарии,

Comment: @Sharon я сам удивился, когда пришел к такому выводу), но так получается, если будут какие-то соображения, буду рад выслушать. Сам пытаюсь это как-то структурировать в голове, опираюсь в данный момент на то, что падеж - это следствие согласования, а не причина. Согласование - это связи между словами в предложении: кто делал, что делал, зачем и как воздействовало, принадлежало, где начало, а где конец логической цепочки.

Comment: Девочка падает на девочку(винительный), девочка не видит девочки(родительный).

Мальчик падает на мальчика, мальчик не видит мальчика. Какой падеж?

Дерево падает на дерево, дерево не ... тут вообще проблема.

Ботинок падает на ботинок(аналогично с деревом), тоже проблема.

Ботинок падает на себя. В общем помогайте, как сможете, я тоже подумаю.

Comment: Девочка падает на девочку(винительный), девочка не видит девочки(родительный).

Мальчик падает на мальчика, мальчик не видит мальчика. Какой падеж?

Дерево падает на дерево, дерево не ... тут вообще проблема.

Ботинок падает на ботинок(аналогично с деревом), тоже проблема.

Ботинок падает на себя. В общем помогайте, как сможете, я тоже подумаю. Почему ботинка - это родительный падеж, а не притяжательное? нет чьего, нет ботинка. Нет чего - лисы, чей - лисий, нет чего - пробки, чей - пробки. Притяжательное! а не родительный падеж.

Comment: @Sharon вот там задали вопрос про "дисканта" - "два самые маленькие дисканта", почему не два самых маленьких дисканта. Дисканта - это притяжательное, от дискант. Две самые маленькие собаки Павлова, а не две самых маленьких собак павлова. Две самые маленькие Павлова.

Comment: Я. наверное, отвечу на ваши вопросы в формате вопрос-ответ. Так будет удобно рассказать кое-что о падежах, а также добавить что-нибудь новое (например, предположить, почему одушевленность выражена именно таким образом). Может, еще кто чего скажет. Тема-то интересная, но доступных сведений по ней не так уж много.