# Почему нам приходится выбирать между винительным и родительным падежом?

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, синтаксический-разбор, родительный-или-винительный

Действительно, такой выбор мы делаем **в следующих случаях:**

(1) Обозначаем партитивность (направленность действия на часть предмета): ***выпить воду — выпить воды.***

(2) Обозначаем отрицание: ***вижу дом — не вижу дома.***

(3) В винительном падеже используем форму Р.п. для одушевленных существительных: ***вижу (кого?) школьника — вижу (что?) карандаш.***

Иногда отрицание и одушевленность присутствуют в **одном** предложении, затрудняя решение, к тому же приходится учитывать **стилистику** (нейтральную или разговорную).

Уж очень много проблем с двумя падежами, но почему **именно с этими?** Это как-то связано с их **значением**? Как **выбирается** каждый из трех вариантов с учетом этого значения?

Спасибо.

Comment: Что значит "с их значением"? У падежей нет значений. Вариантов же два, а не три (неправильно сформулировали мысль).

Comment: https://studfile.net/preview/2868293/page:4/

Comment: Это больше роль. Значение слова от падежа-то не меняется.

Comment: Нет. В грамматике говорится о функции, о значении и о том, какие отношения между глаголом и существительным выражает каждый конкретный падеж. При описании падежа используются глаголы "означает, обозначает".  Вы из-за этого термина хотите закрыть мой вопрос?

Comment: Но значение — это же смысл (по словарям). А смысл не меняется. Предназначение — это не значение. *но почему именно с этими?* — с таким же успехом можно спросить, почему в русском языке 6 падежей. Больше тема для диссертации, слишком в общем.

Comment: Вы грамматику читайте, чтобы знать терминологию.  Падеж – это лексико-грамматическая категория, то есть рассматривается с точки зрения семантики и грамматики. И это практический вопрос, так как тема различения двух падежей на форуме присутствует постоянно. Меня не интересует чистая теория вопроса, но интересует применение  этой теории на практике. Если не понимать значение падежей, то выбор можно сделать только формально и не всегда удачно.

Comment: (1) _воды_  в данном случае партитив, никакого выбора между родительным и винительным нет. (2) - вижу дом, точно так же не вижу дом. Нет никакого обязательного выбора. (3) _Школьника_ - винительный падеж. Нет никакого выбора.

Comment: Пожалуйста, давайте ответы, а не комментарии.  Обсуждать тему в комментариях неудобно. И дайте ссылку на источник. В Грамматике-80 говорится о замене винительного падежа родительным во всех случаях. Если что-то изменилось в терминологии, то это будет интересно узнать, но напишите об этом в поле ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрим в качестве примера **глагольное беспредложное управление.**

При выборе падежа, а также при объяснении темы одушевленности/неодушевленности, можно ориентироваться на различие между **основными значениями** винительного и именительного падежа.

1. **Основным значением В.п.** является направленность  действия на предмет и **полный охват** его действием. В этом случае мы имеем переходный  глагол и прямое дополнение: ***вижу дом, люблю стихи.***
2. **Основными значением Р.п.** является действие, также направленное на предмет,  но не целиком, а только **до границ предмета** (отложительно-достигательное значение). Второе значение Р.п. — это действие, которое распространяется **на часть предмета** (партитивное значение Р.п.)

Таким образом, Р.п. может обозначать партитивные отношения для переходных глаголов (***выпил воду — выпил воды***).

Кроме того, отложительно-достигательный Р.п. используется при обозначении **желания, поиска, достижения/удаления**: желать, хотеть (счастья, славы, успеха); достичь чего-н., опасаться, остерегаться, бояться, стыдиться кого-чего-н.; слушаться кого-н.; касаться кого-чего-н.

Но там его также **может заменять В.п**. прямого объекта с полным охватом предмета действием: ждать (что?)  ***хорошую погоду*** — ждать (чего) **хорошей погоды.**  У Розенталя [§200. Выбор падежной формы](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)

3. **При отрицании** также проявляется различие основных значений двух падежей. Родительный падеж **обозначает отрицание** в таком предложении: *Я имею дом/не имею дома.* Здесь действие не может распространиться  на весь предмет целиком **при его отсутствии.** В то же время «единая старая норма обязательного родительного падежа при глаголах с отрицанием в современном языке под влиянием разговорной речи **не выдерживается**: во многих случаях употребление винительного падежа не только предпочитается, но и является единственно правильным».

ПРИМЕРЫ. Родительный падеж заменяет винительный при отрицании : ***люблю стихи — не люблю ***стихов***.*** Винительный падеж используется и при отрицании (при указании на конкретный объект): Не наклоняй ***знамя-то.***.. (Горький);   Розенталь [§201. Падеж дополнения при переходных глаголах с отрицанием](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm)

4. При объяснении темы одушевленности/неодушевленности отметим, что **форма Р.п**. используется вместо формы В.п. для одуш. существительных м. и ср. рода 2-го скл. и сущ. мн.числа, а также в падежном вопросе ***кого?***. Но почему?

Можно предположить, что для одушевленных предметов важно **отличить** подлежащее от дополнения. Ученик (кто? И.п.) читает (что? В.п.) роман. Ученик (кто? И.п.) знает (кого? В.п.) всех героев. Противопоставление: ***кто*** (субъект) — ***кого*** (объект).

Таким образом, обобщенное значение двух падежей может служить **ориентиром** при решении различных частных задач.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Интересно посмотреть, как **падежи делят между собой область** применения (территорию). Это нужно для определения **стиля** речи (нейтр. или  разг.).

(1) В теме **партитивных отношений** Р.п. заходит на территорию В.п., но он уточняет семантику. Поэтому оба падежа нейтральны.

(2) В теме **отрицания** основным является Р.п., а В.п. предлагает, к примеру, подчеркнуть **конкретику.** Сейчас они сосуществуют по определенным правилам, но при свободном выборе В.п. будет считаться разговорным.

(3) **В теме направленности** действия без полного охвата предмета (желание, стремление и т.д.) основным является Р.п. (нейтр.), а В.п. опять же подчеркивает **конкретику** предметов (ближе к разг.)

(4) Проблемы могут возникнуть и **при выборе В.п** для неодушевленных предметов, когда при наличии **отрицания** Р.п. может претендовать на территорию В.п. Такие задачи особенно **сложны** и решаются по контексту. Вот пример  **[сложного вопроса](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474802/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85)**

**ПРИМЕРЫ** (выбор нужного падежа по Нацкорпусу)

В примерах можно определить падеж и какие факторы влияют на его выбор, при этом надо учитывать две формы В.п.

**Утверждение**

*Жаль маленькую внучку, жаль этих месяцев. Может, ему варенья жалко?
Жалко брелок. Жалко Машку. Колюнчику было очень жалко папу.
Мне других бывает жалко. Вот котелок жалко. Родителей жалко. И ей стало этого зайца жалко.*

**Отрицание**

*Неужели тебе товарища не жалко! Денег не жалко! Мне мотоцикла не жалко в конце концов. Ему родной дочери не жалко. Нам для них жизни не жалко, не то что какого-то дома! Кому своего добра не жалко! Вам своего времени-то не жалко?  А избу бы не жалко, живите.*

При ответе использованы **материалы**:

1. Русская грамматика ,1980 г. 2. Русская грамматика (под ред. Шведовой и Лопатина), 1990 г.

Comment: _«…Единая старая норма обязательного родительного падежа **при глаголах с отрицанием** в современном языке под влиянием разговорной речи не выдерживается: во многих случаях употребление винительного падежа не только предпочитается, но и является единственно правильным». Сравнить: **люблю стихи — не люблю стихов**»._ ❓❓❓

Comment: Спасибо, отредактировала неясный текст.

Comment: «_В  примерах можно определить падеж и какие факторы влияют на его выбор, при этом надо учитывать две формы В.п. <…>  **А избу бы не жалко, живите.**_» === Смешно!  И какие же факторы требуют именно винительного падежа в этом примере из «Матрёниного двора»?

Comment: _«А что смешного? Художественный текст…»_ === Смешон не сам текст, а это Ваше: «В примерах можно определить падеж и какие факторы влияют на его выбор».  Приведённое предложение, сказанное малограмотной женщиной (это не авторский текст), останется неграмотным при любом падеже слова «изба». И  искать  _**факторы**_, повлиявшие на выбор ею винительного падежа вкупе с частицей «бы» – это впустую ля-ля травить. Это моё мнение. Вы, похоже, думаете иначе…

Comment: Да, я думаю иначе.  Здесь важна не грамотность персонажа, а умение автора передать стилевые особенности речи. Это предикативное наречие – сложный пример для анализа при выборе падежа, там надо учитывать ряд факторов. И если Вы этого не видите, то это ваши проблемы. Подсказывать не буду,  учитывая стилистику Вашей речи (впустую ля-ля травить). Матрена так не стала бы говорить, хотя она и малограмотная.  Мы ведь с Вами недостаточно знакомы, чтобы  Вы  могли давать подобные оценки.  Я полагаю, что  Вы проявляете недружественность.  Но Вы, похоже, думаете иначе и ведете себя очень раскованно.

Answer (score 1):

Мне не понятно, почему сравниваются глагол с отрицательным глаголом?

Не знаю, но я пока обозначу так: не вижу дом - не вижу дома.

А можно сделать так: не вижу твой дом - не вижу твоего дома / не вижу ты дома - не вижу тебя дома. У фразы "не вижу дома" могут быть три из этих звучаний.

Пока это не ответ, но я думаю, как написать.

У меня появляется подозрение, что дело не в управлении, а в том, что родительный падеж - это своеобразный референс на дом, домом не являющийся. Не вижу крышу дома, не вижу крыши дома, не вижу - дома.

То есть расширяя еще немного можно получить следующее:

Не вижу крышу (у/от) дома, не вижу крыши у/от дома.

Диалог может быть следующим:

- Видишь? - Нет, не вижу дома... хотя, вижу, вижу крышу(у/от дома)!

То есть каким-то образом собеседник догадался, что если дома, то речь идет не о доме, а о части дома - например, крыше. И в последней части уточнения не нужно, что "дома" и предлога не нужно, прелог так же "съедается" родительным падежом.

Comment: Ну да, трубы нет, крыши нет, кажется, там вообще ничего нет. Нет там никакого дома!  Где ты его увидел? Так наше сознание по частям считывает информацию с действительности...

Comment: Насчет партитивности воды тут сложнее, так как не ясно, это партативность воды или вод? То есть вода - это партитивность вод, а воды - это партитивность вода? То есть, вот то что я у себя писал: cупруга - это партитивность супруг.

Comment: Ну и можно сравнить жениться - глагол, а замуж - наречие, за+муж(ем) дословно. То есть жён это какое-то производное понятие от жениться или жено(тут вообще средний род). Жена - это партитивность. То есть 1 склонения женского рода образуются через партитивность.

Comment: Я вам объясняю отрицание:  как я его понимаю по вашей модели. И зря вы работаете с окончаниями напрямую, они многозначные, сложились исторически. Раньше у нас было вообще 6 склонений в зависимости от основы, а не по родам, поэтому вряд ли они несут конкретную информацию..

Comment: Хотя, вода вроде от индоевропейского uda - уда?, и может вод - это новоизобретение, а вода за счет окончания А стала женского рода. Хотя не мне известно наличие родов в санскрите и тп) есть они или нет. Вообще, есть какая-то инфа откуда склонения появились?

Comment: @Sharon я не говорю, что это так оно и есть, но это так работает. Если у вас есть два одинаковых звучания(а тут даже не два), то они волей неволей будут попадать в одну корзину и пересекаться. То есть оно становится одинаковым, хотите вы этого или нет. То есть грубо говоря, язык можно сдизайнерить так, пересечь определенные слова и смыслы, и это будет ассоциироваться следующим образом. Если вы выходите из одного и попадаете в другое одинаковое - это одинаковые значения. С другой стороны если есть разница, в ударениях, в смягчении-оглушении - то это дает другие звучания и как следствие значения

Comment: @Sharon Этимология > семантики, а звучание > значения. То что звучит одинаково будет тяготеть к ассоциативной связи с чем-то общим, одинаковое звучание стирает оба значения, заменяет их референсом.

Comment: Вот я и говорю: не смотрите на окончания, на форму, а то сделаете неправильный вывод. Подведет вас многозначная форма. Источник  о склонениях не могу указать, но знаю,что они зависели от основы (раньше сочетаемость звуков была ограниченной, вот и приходилось подбирать разные окончания). Потом все объединили и получили три склонения.

Comment: @Sharon звук - это форма и есть. А значение - это иллюзия формы, а не форма. Если нет разницы звучаний/употреблений, пониманий - то значения стираются и заменяются чем-то другим. То есть я могу взять и соединить эти два значения без формы. Задать любое новое, и в конце концов оно будет главенствующим, потому что прошлые конфликтовали между собой и каждое из них не было достаточно верным. Либо победит то, у которого будет больше связности. Основа языка - это связанность с групп слов и их корней.

Comment: Это уже философия. Как у нас сейчас: мнимое это и есть действительное, и наоборот.  Но тогда пусть действительность будет рабочей моделью, в которой мы живем и  вполне себе ориентируемся. Так и с формой. Опыт показывает,что содержание главнее формы, что форма всего лишь выражает содержание.

Comment: @Sharon в общем у меня появилась идея, что язык как целостная система, тем более мощный, чем слова в нем связаны. Русский очень связанный, и его можно еще связать с другими языками, тогда он будет центром этих языков что ли. По сути этим и занимался Фасмер тот же и прочие деятели. Но для своих языков. Англичане свои корни тоже так связывают, но всем другим они задают значения, семантику.

Comment: @Sharon не, тут не философия, это все прозрачно. Камень всегда тяжелее, чем метафизический камень и даже чем метафизический слон. Однако если метафизический камень это рефенс на реальную гору, тут камень может проиграть, но только реальной горе. Содержание да, значение нет.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо  за ответ, я в этих областях не особо разбираюсь, не самый лучший для вас собеседник.

Comment: @Sharon да я тоже не разбираюсь, потому и пытаюсь разобраться, почему так.

Comment: Не, в языкознании вы разбираетесь,  а мне  грамматику как она есть (со значением и формой) еще в школе в голову вложили) Для меня это рабочая модель. Я вообще очень люблю методику моделей при описании сложных вещей, так легче живется)

Comment: @Sharon спасибо, но я правда не разбираюсь, у меня как раз формы нет, поэтому я и пишу так странно, знал бы я форму, а не воспринимал то, что встречаю, было бы все понятнее и стандартнее. А так приходится выдумывать на ходу, поддерживая беседу и изучая науку через незнакомый язык научного знания.