# "Пожалей молодецкого плеча". Это родительный или винительный падеж?

Tags: морфология, родительный-или-винительный

Н.А. Некрасов, **"Коробейники"**

*Ой, полна, полна коробушка,*

*Есть и ситец и парча.*

*Пожалей, душа моя зазнобушка,*

*Молодецкого плеча!*

На выбор падежа влияют **разные факторы,** иногда сложно выбрать.

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474825/Почему-нам-приходится-выбирать-между-винительным-и-родительным-падежом](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474825/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BC)